# Similarity score between athletes

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, similarities

I have a question about finding a similarity score between athletes. I have players that each have 6-10 variables each. How can I calculate a similarity score as a percentage in order to compare them?

The issue is that the data are all on different scales (i.e. weight in pounds, time in seconds, etc.) and also some players are missing some values.

I thought about just using the absolute value of the values, but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Usually you would use something like $s(x,y) = \|x-y \|_{2}^{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide an example, as I'm not quite sure I understand the formula in this case?